# How to stub DataMapper association with RSpec2?

Tags: ruby, testing, datamapper, rspec2, stub

I'm trying to write some specs and want to stub out the calls to the database so I don't rely on an actual filled database to get the tests running.

Now I don't really know how to stub the calls between associations using DataMapper.

Here are two example models:

```
class Foo
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id, Serial

  has n, :bars
end

class Bar
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id, Serial

  belongs_to :foo
end
```

Now I want to stub the call to `Foo.first('foobar')` and `Foo.first('foobar').bars` 
The first one is no problem using `Foo.stub(:first) { #etc }` but I don't know how to stub the second call to its associations.
Something like `Foo.stub(:bars) { #etc }` is not working.

Does anyone know how to do it? Is this approach even correct?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a mock_model.

```
foo = mock(Foo).as_null_object
foo.stub(:bars)
Foo.stub(:first).and_return(foo)
```

The reason for the as_null_object is that RSpec will return false by default when asked if it respends to a method that it hasn't been told to expect.

If that doesn't work, then create an instance of foo.

```
foo = Foo.create(:example => "data") #Or create with a factory a factory
foo.stub(:bars)
Foo.stub(:first).and_return(foo)
```

Then when you do:

```
Foo.first('foobar').bars
```

it will use the stub on line 2 as the first call will return that instance of foo.

Answer (score 0):

not tested, but it should work:

```
Foo.stub(:first) { ... }
foo = Foo.first('foobar')
foo.stub(:bars) { ... }
```

regards,

A.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `stub_chain` method:

```
Foo.stub_chain(:first, :bars).and_return(:whatever)
```